# Sandboxing child processes: why is script different than app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

My app is sandboxed (and cannot open or write any file). I was curious what happened to child processes. I had my app execute a bash script (that just writes to a file). The behaviour was expected: the script, launched by my sandboxed app, was sandboxed too.

However, when I tried to have my app launch another app (not mine), the child app was not sandboxed. I was curious what was different?

I launch my script with

```
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments:@[@"path/to/script.sh"]];
[task launch];
```

and my app with

```
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];
[task setArguments:@[@"-a", @"/Applications/some.app"]];
[task launch];
```

(the same problem happens when launching the app with `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/some.app"];`)

Note: I do not control some.app, it could be any app. I have read [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW15) too but understand that it works only if we own some.app too

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided only applies to processes that your app launches via NSTask or the posix-spawn function: command-line tools and scripts and such. When you ask your app to launch a full, independent app, that app will have its own sandbox and entitlements, and will be governed by the security protocols that the system normally applies to applications: e.g., the user will have to approve running it, and it will be limited by its own entitlements.

There's no need for an independent app to inherit your app's sandbox, since it has its own. In fact, allowing it to inherit your app's sandbox might be a security risk in its own right, since someone unscrupulous could use that trick to escalate the entitlements of an app beyond what it originally had.